# What are some types and/or terms in system-f that cannot be expressed in Hindley Milner

Tags: types, type-inference, lambda-calculus, hindley-milner

I remember reading somewhere that Hindley Milner was a restriction on system-f. If that is the case, could someone please provide me with some terms that can be typed in system-f but not in HM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything involving higher-ranked (i.e. "first-class") polymorphism. For example:

```
lambda (f : forall A. A -> A). (f Int 1, f String "hello")
```

This function would have the type `(forall A. A -> A) -> Int * String`, which is not expressible in HM, where all polymorphic type schemes must be in "prenex" form (i.e. the quantifier may only occur on the outside, never nested).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, that expression is not a function. Definitions (bound via let) can be polymorphic with HM, but function parameters can not.